# Append() instruction does not work in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to do a word counter with mapreduce using concurrent.futures. The problem is that in the shuffle function (adds a 1 to the dictionary list if that word exists) I have a shared dictionary "word_map_result" in which all processes look if the key exists, if it exists they perform the append(1), if that key does not exist they create the list with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwY1y.png). The problem is that doing shuffle_dict_result[word_map_result[i][0]].append(1) does not work, because it does not add it.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? I don't understand it. How could I perform this function of the program?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Emphasis on *minimal*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.append()` on the list value retrieved from `Manager().dict()`.  Accessing a managed object returns a *new* proxy object each time and `.append()` ends up modifying the list proxy and not the managed dictionary.  Instead assign a new value to the dict proxy will update the Manager().dict() correctly.

Minimal example using the incorrect and correct method:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(d):
    print('func before',d)
    d[0].append(1)  # won't work
    d[1] += [3]     # assigns a new value (d[1] = d[1] + [3] works too)
    print('func result',d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as m:
        d = m.dict()
        d[0] = [0]
        d[1] = [2]
        print('main before',d)
        p = mp.Process(target=func,args=(d,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print('main result',d)
```

```
main before {0: [0], 1: [2]}
func before {0: [0], 1: [2]}
func result {0: [0], 1: [2, 3]}    # note key 0 didn't change...new proxy object
main result {0: [0], 1: [2, 3]}    # += worked for key 1
```

Comment: Note that `d[1] += [3]` is the best of all worlds; it reassigns, so it triggers the manager to update, but it actually updated the `list` in place (unlike `d[1] = d[1] + [3]` which makes a brand new `list` and replaces the old one), keeping the cost of repeated appending to amortized `O(1)` (though the manager update itself may or may not take advantage of that; I suspect not, but haven't delved into the code).

Comment: Note, however, that the following *does* work: `lst = d[0]; lst.append(1); d[0] = lst`

Comment: @Booboo That’s reassigning the key as mentioned in the answer, but less efficient as ShadowRanger pointed out.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Agreed.